# How to Postback button html to server with javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

In my HTML:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
<asp:TextBox ID="_searchKeyword" runat="server" Width="450" Height="42"></asp:TextBox>
<div style="display:none">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="_searchLinkButton" OnClick="SearchButton" runat="server">Search</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

When I click the `button` element, I want the to postback to the server and run the `SearchButton` method.

In my code behind:

```
protected void SearchButton(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string typeValue = _hdDropDown.Value;
    if (typeValue == "All")
    {
        typeValue = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this, do I need JavaScript?

Comment: what do you want? the equivalent fo that code but using plain javascript and HTML?

Comment: How can you call SearchButton function if the corresponding link button is not visible ?

Comment: @jack.the.rippe i want to use javascript to call function searchbutton when i click the button element

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot use and Asp:Button element?

My first suggestion would be to use an Asp:Button element rather than your current set up but if, for whatever reason, you can't then I'd suggest giving the button a name and then with jQuery you can do:

```
$('#submitbuttonid').click(function(){$('#_searchLinkButton').click();});
```

Or in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit buttonid');

    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
var linkBtn = document.getElementById('_searchLinkButton');

linkBtn.onClick();
});
```

Comment: it's not working, the SearchButton method is not running

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! The reason my well be because the I'd is different at runtime. Add ClientIDMode="Static" to the asp: elements when selecting by id, or select them by class or you can use '[id*=controlid]' for the jquery selector

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the old **do post back** method:

```
function callServer() {
__doPostBack('<%= myButton.UniqueID %>','');
}
```